# Why don't JournalEntry Entity Refs update correctly?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When updating JournalEntry objects using the Intuit QBO v3 API, I am unable to *remove* an existing Entity.

Here's a subset of the object json dict I get back on the read:

```
{
    "Id": "16",
    "Amount": 20000.0,
    "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
    "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
      "PostingType": "Credit",
      "Entity": {
        "Type": "Customer",
        "EntityRef": {
          "value": "2833",
          "name": "My Unwanted Entity Name"
        }
      },
      "AccountRef": {
        "value": "590",
        "name": "My Account Name"
      }
    }
  },
```

Here's the subset of what I give back in the update request body:

```
{
    "Id": "16",
    "Amount": 20000.0,
    "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail",
    "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
      "PostingType": "Credit",
      "AccountRef": {
        "value": "590",
        "name": "My Account Name"
      }
    }
  },
```

The resulting update does **not** remove the Entity though. In fact, it doesn't even appear that there's an update operation performed at all. (The SyncToken does not increment.) FWIW, I also tried passing in a blank dict ({}) and also null. Neither idea worked.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug for this QBO-96488.
The entity node is not deleting on update.
Going fwd please post your question on Lice community for faster response-
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com